# How to ggplot two variables with a specific colour and legend with missing values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, reshape2

I am trying to use `ggplot2` to plot two variables over time. The variables have missing values which differ. e.g:

```
       Date   Var1      Var2
3 2016-06-16        NA    NA
4 2016-06-17    0.0035 0.004
5 2016-06-18        NA    NA
6 2016-06-19    0.0825 0.083
7 2016-06-20    0.0890    NA
8 2016-06-21    0.1725 0.173
```

I want to plot this with `geom_point()` and the points connected by dotted lines and not leave gaps where there is missing data but also have a legend so I have the following:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Date))

plot1 <- plot1 + geom_point(data= 
mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var1),],aes(y= Var1, colour = 
"Var1"), size =8, col = "navyblue") +
  geom_line(data= mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var1),],aes(y= Var1, 
group =1, colour = "Var1"), linetype = 6, lwd = 1, col = "navyblue") +
  geom_point(data = mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var2),], aes(y=cal5C, colour 
= "Var2"), size=8, col = "turquoise3") +
  geom_line(data = mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var2),],aes(y=Var2, group = 
1, colour = "Var2"), linetype =6, col = "turquoise3")
```

Which works nicely both lines are plotted the desired colour with points and lines connecting and I can then adjust the theme etc. to make it look prettier.

However a legend does not show - it does appear when I drop my colour specification i.e.:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Date))
plot1 <- plot1 + geom_point(data= mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var1),],aes(y= 
Var1, colour = "Var1"), size =8) +
  geom_line(data= mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var1),],aes(y= Var1, group =1, 
 colour = "Var1"), linetype = 6, lwd = 1) +
  geom_point(data = mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var2),], aes(y=Var2, colour = 
"Var2"), size=8) +
  geom_line(data = mydata[!is.na(mydata$Var2),],aes(y=Var2, group = 1, 
colour = "Var2"), linetype =6)
```

But I don't want to use the preset colours for my graph. I have seen people using the reshape package which I have tried but then I am not sure how to get the lines to connect between the points - the best I have is the the lines connect between all the points, which is not useful.

This is what I have using the reshape and melt to get it into long format:

```
library(reshape2)
mydata2 <- mydata[,c(1,26,28)] #subsets into 3 columns Date, Var1, Va2
mydata.m <- melt(mydata2, id.vars=c("Date"))
head(mydata.m)
   Date  variable  value  
1 2016-06-16 Var1     NA  
2 2016-06-17 Var1  0.0035  
3 2016-06-18 Var1      NA  
4 2016-06-19 Var1  0.0825  
5 2016-06-20 Var1  0.0890  
6 2016-06-21 Var1  0.1725
```

and then plotting it:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mydata.m, 
            aes(x=Date, y=value, color=variable))
plot1 <- plot1 + geom_point() + geom_line()               
plot1 <- plot1 + scale_color_manual(name="", values = 
c("navyblue","turquoise3"))
```

This plots just the points, a legend and the right colour but I cannot work out how to get the `geom_line()` to work - I have tried incorporating the `mydata.m[!is.na(mydata.m$value), ]` into the `geom_line()` after reshaping but it does not work and `geom_line(group = 2)` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the functions `complete.case()` or `is.na()` can be used to remove rows with missing values from the molten data set `mydata.m` but it has to be passed to the `data` parameter, e.g.,

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mydata.m[complete.cases(mydata.m), ], 
                aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable, group = variable))

# or, using !is.na():
plot1 <- ggplot(mydata.m[!is.na(mydata.m$value), ], 
                aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable, group = variable))

plot1 <- plot1 + geom_point() + geom_line()               
plot1 <- plot1 + scale_color_manual(name="", values = 
                                      c("navyblue","turquoise3")) 
plot1
```

[image]

Note that `aes(..., group = variable)` tells `ggplot2` which of the data points belong to one group and should be connected by a line.

Comment: Hi @Uwe thanks for your reply - i have just tried using the code you have posted and for some reason i am still not getting the line connection just this error:
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Should i be adding something else here - i am not really that familiar with working with the reshape format?

Comment: Please, try to add `group = variable` In the call to `aes()`.